Quotient topology induces weaker topology on the original space.
Reminders:
Lets say we have a surjective map $p:(X,\tau_X)\to Y$ where $Y$ is just a set.
We can define a quotient topology via $p$ on the set $Y$ as :
$\tau_Y:=\{V\subset Y\;|\; p^{-1}(V) \in \tau_X\}$
Now if we define $\tau:=\{p^{-1}(V)\subset X\;|\; V\in \tau_Y\}\subset \tau_X$
So we have $1-1$ correspondence with open sets of $Y$ and our new topology $\tau$ on the set $X$.
Question: Under what conditions we can say that $(X,\tau)\approx (Y,\tau_Y)$, so we end up with weaker topology on $X$ which is homeomorphic to $Y$ with quotient topology by $p:(X,\tau_X)\to Y$.
Motivation: I am motivated by the 1-1 correspondence of open sets between quotient topology on Y and X. But we need to construct a bijection between X and Y again which is subtle. Is there any info on this question.
